# Exception in Magento log: the element can't have a child

Tags: product, xml, custom-block, custom-theme, catalog-product

I found the following errors in the `exception.log` and `debug.log` files in `/var/log folder`:

```
[2019-12-17 16:23:05] main.CRITICAL: The element "product.info.options" can't have a child because "product.info.options" already has a child with alias "default". {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): The element \"product.info.options\" can't have a child because \"product.info.options\" already has a child with alias \"default\". at /home/xxxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:625)"} []
[2019-12-17 16:23:05] main.CRITICAL: The element "product.info.options" can't have a child because "product.info.options" already has a child with alias "text". {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): The element \"product.info.options\" can't have a child because \"product.info.options\" already has a child with alias \"text\". at /home/xxxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:625)"} []
[2019-12-17 16:23:05] main.CRITICAL: The element "product.info.options" can't have a child because "product.info.options" already has a child with alias "file". {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): The element \"product.info.options\" can't have a child because \"product.info.options\" already has a child with alias \"file\". at /home/xxxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:625)"} []
[2019-12-17 16:23:05] main.CRITICAL: The element "product.info.options" can't have a child because "product.info.options" already has a child with alias "select". {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): The element \"product.info.options\" can't have a child because \"product.info.options\" already has a child with alias \"select\". at /home/xxxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:625)"} []
[2019-12-17 16:23:05] main.CRITICAL: The element "product.info.options" can't have a child because "product.info.options" already has a child with alias "date". {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): The element \"product.info.options\" can't have a child because \"product.info.options\" already has a child with alias \"date\". at /home/xxxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:625)"} []
```

Besides, in the `catalog_product_view.xml` file this is the block `product.info.options`.

```
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="product/view/form.phtml" after="estimated.delivery" before="product.info.details">
                    <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                    </container>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.form.options" as="options_container">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="product/view/options.phtml">
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" as="default" template="product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" as="text" template="product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" as="file" template="product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" as="select" template="product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" as="date" template="product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
                            </block>
                            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
```

Any idea on how to resolve this issue of the template?

Answer (score 2):

What solved the exception for me was doing the following:

If you open the original file:

app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

You'll see that there's a difference because the children have names assigned.

But in your xml from your theme, you don't have the names.

[image]

So adding the name attribute to the children of `product.info.options` stopped the exception in my case.

Btw don't forget to clear Magento cache.

References:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/8514/files

Answer (score 0):

The names and alias of each blocks have to be unique. you have to find in your theme the following snippets.

```
as="default" , as="text" , as="file , as="select" , as="date"
```